# define custom model in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

let us consider following simulink model

[image]

i have following matrix

```
 A=[2 1 3;1 4 5]

A =

     2     1     3
     1     4     5
```

and its singular value decomposition

```
>> [U E V]=svd(A)

U =

   -0.4719   -0.8817
   -0.8817    0.4719


E =

    7.2965         0         0
         0    1.6617         0


V =

   -0.2502   -0.7772   -0.5774
   -0.5480    0.6053   -0.5774
   -0.7982   -0.1720    0.5774

>>
```

in custom matlab function taken form this link

http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html

i have created my own function

```
function [U,E,V]=singular_decomposition(A)
%#codegen
[U E V]=svd(A);
```

numeric values and  dimension of matrices are same,but at some point there is sign different,how can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong. SVD decomposition of a matrix is in general not unique.

If you perform `U*E*V'` you'll get the same value of A in both cases.

Comment: @datodatuashvili yes you can check the results of `U*E*V'` from console command as well as simulink display, both must evaluate to `A`

Comment: about uniqueness, i have found following link http://www4.ncsu.edu/~ipsen/REU09/chapter4.pdf

Comment: @datodatuashvili **Remark 4.2** _"The singular values are unique, but the singular vector matrices are not."_ And please don't throw maths on me, I am poor at it, if unsatisfied, you can post it on math.stackexchange.com. IMHO its implementation defined